# Is it possible for Boost's lockfree queue to lose elements?

Tags: c++, boost, lock-free

I have a *single-threaded* application that uses `boost::lockfree::queue` (from Boost 1.57). (The reason I'm using the queue is that it's part of a library that's also used in a multi-threaded application.)

It appears that the queue is somehow losing elements.

The class that uses the queue behaves as follows:

- There are two separate functions that call `push` on the queue. There is no thread-safety logic beyond what is provided by the queue itself.
- There is *one* function that consumes elements from the queue; it consumes *all* elements, using a `while(my_queue.pop(temp_element))` loop. This function is protected by a mutex to ensure that all elements go to a *single* consumer. However, if two *duplicate* elements (compared with `==`) are detected in a row, the second element is skipped.

I observed that elements appeared not to be consistently propagated through the system, so using `std::atomic_uint`s, I created some counters to check that the same number of alerts are leaving the queue as entering it:

- There are separate counters for each of the two `push`ing methods. We'll call these `pushed_method1` and `pushed_method2`.
- There are separate counters for "processed" elements and "skipped" elements. We'll call these `consumed` and `skipped`. In the loop, they're updated as follows (with variables renamed, and with descriptive pseudocode in `[square brackets]`):

  ```
  ElementType previous{[ initialize in invalid state ]};
  while (my_queue.pop(temp_element))
  {
    if (! [ check if `previous` is valid ]
        || previous != temp_element)
    {
      [ ... log a message ]
      [ ... insert the element into a vector to be returned ]

      ++consumed;
    }
    else
    {
      // ... log a message

      ++skipped;
    }

    previous = temp_element;
  }
  ```

Following the loop, I check the state of the counters and the queue and do my sanity checking:

```
auto postconsume_pushed_method1 = pushed_method1.load();
auto postconsume_pushed_method2 = pushed_method2.load();
auto all_consumed = my_queue.empty();

assert(
    !all_consumed
  ||  postconsume_pushed_method1 + postconsume_pushed_method2
        == consumed + skipped);
```

This assertion *usually* passes--but it **sometimes fails** in my **single-threaded app**. (It also sometimes fails in the multi-threaded case, but I would expect focusing on the single-threaded case to simplify the problem.)

In the multi-threaded case, I could imagine that the operations are being re-ordered so that one or more `load`s occur after the `.empty()` check, but I'd hope that's not the case since I'd expect `std::atomic` and `boost::lockfree` to include memory fences for that sort of thing.

However, in the single-threaded case, this *shouldn't matter*, because elements should *never* be `push`ed while the app is executing the "consume" method, and the alert-queue should *always* be empty following the loop (since the loop won't break until `pop` returns `false`).

Am I misunderstanding something? Is there an error in my logic? Is there even a small chance that I've found a bug in `boost::lockfree::queue`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The queue is lock-free, so that `push` does not block when the queue if full.

`lockfree::queue::push` returns a boolean telling whether the element has made it into the queue. When the queue is full `push` returns `false`, so you may like to check for this condition.

Comment: Thank you, I had completely forgotten that I was using a fixed-size queue. Is it ever possible for `push` to return `false` when when using a dynamically-sized queue?

Comment: @KyleStrand It can return `false` if it fails to allocate memory for the element being pushed. You must check the return value, no shortcut for non-blocking containers, I am afraid.